# What is $ {n\choose k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, notation, binomial-theorem

This is the Binomial theorem:

$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}a^{n-k}b^k.$$

I do not understand the symbol 
$ {n\choose k}.$ How do I actually compute this? What does this notation mean? Help is appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: This is binomial theorem, not binomial series what you expct. Were they mxed here.

Comment: You need $a+b$ in the bracket on the left-hand side, then it makes sense.Mixing $x$ and $b$ is probably what is confusing you.

Comment: I've edited a minute ago

Answer (score 10):

$n \choose k$ - n choose k - how many different ways there are to pick $k$ items from a set of $n$ elements. The explanation starts from permutations, through combinations, finishing with binomial theory. If you are familiar with the formulas and *the ideas* behind them feel free to skip some steps.

### [Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)

A permutation of a set $\mathcal{S}$ is an arrangement of its elements in a specific order. The number of possible permutations is denoted as $P$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
P^n_n &= n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots1 \\\\
      &= n!
\end{aligned}
$$

**The idea behind the formula:** on the first pick we can choose from $n$ elements - $n$ possible picks. After picking the first element, we are left with $n-1$ elements from which to choose. Following this logic, eventually, we are left with $2$ elements from which to choose and then finally $1$.

It can be observed that we can *prematurely* end this process and only choose $k$ elements from $\mathcal{S}$:

$$
P^n_k=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-(k-1))
$$

The idea is the same just that we stop after our $k$-th pick, during which we had $n-(k-1)$ choices as we already picked $k-1$ elements.

### [Combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

The base idea behind combinations is that one is picking $k$ elements from the set $\mathcal{S}$ of size $n$ but **not** putting them in a sequence - meaning that the order is **not** important. We can view combinations as creating a subset 
$\mathcal{S'}\subseteq\mathcal{S}$, of size $k$, $k\leq n$. The number of possible ways we can create this subset $\mathcal{S'}$ from the set $\mathcal{S}$ is denoted as $C$ and defined as:

$$
\begin{align}
C^n_k & = {n\choose k} \\\\
  &=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-(k-1))}{k!} \\\\
  &= \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}
\end{align}
$$

Observe how the numerator is equivalent to $P^n_k$ and the denominator to $P^k_k$.

**The idea behind the formula:** notice that the extra variability in $P^n_k$ comes from the different permutations ($P^k_k$) each of those combinations ($C^n_k$) can make. To put this in mathematical terms:
$$
\begin{align}
P^n_k &= C^n_kP^k_k \\\\
      &\Rightarrow \\\\
C^n_k &= \frac{P^n_k}{P^k_k} \\\\
      &= \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-(k-1))}{k!} \\\\
      &= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
\end{align}
$$

### [Binomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Combinatorial_interpretation)

Let's take the example of $(x+y)^n$ and write it as a product of $n$ binomials:

$$
(x+y)^n = (x+y)(x+y)\cdots(x+y)
$$

If we were to expand this, each resulting *term* in the expansion will be a product of $n$ terms, one term picked from each of the binomials above. We need to focus only on $x$ (one of the terms) - if we choose to pick $x$ $k$ times then we **must** pick $y$ $n-k$ times. There are $n$ binomials in the expansions and we are making $k$ picks, therefore, the number of resulting terms in the expansion with the $k$ picks of $x$ is $C^n_k$ or $n\choose k$.

Answer (score 7):

The symbol ${n\choose k}$ is read as "$n$ choose $k$." It represents the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from a set of $n$ objects. It has the following formula
$$ {n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}.$$
Here, 
$$ n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots2\cdot1.$$

Comment: I have also heard the equation to be called binomial expansion. Can you give an example of how exactly that is done? The resources I have searched for are not very clear.

Comment: Sorry, can you restate your question?

Comment: Could I use the binomial theorem to do binomial expansion? If so, how could that be done?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the binomial theorem and the binomial expansion are basically the same.

Comment: I figured that, I am looking for a good example of which.

Answer (score 5):

$$\binom{n}{k}= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

It computes the number of ways we can choose $k$ items out of $n$ items.

Answer (score 2):

$\binom{n}{k}:=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$

With $n!=n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot\dotso\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1=\prod_{i=1}^n i$

Answer (score 2):

$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} $

It is used to calculate the number of ways "k" events can occur in "n" choices.

Answer (score 1):

$${n\choose k}={n!\over k!(n-k)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let me try a simple explanation.

*"n choose k"*, it's a ***Combination***.

${n\choose k}$ is a way to express the number of choices one has when selecting a "bunch" of things from a collection. The number of *combinations* that can be made of $k$ unique elements from a set of $n$.

For example, the number of starting teams a coach could select for a match out of all available players. A simpler example would be picking up $2$ strikers from a group of $3$ ready players, which gives us $3$ combinations.

$$Strikers:\{Pelé, Maradona, Eusebio\}$$
There are 3 different ways to choose the starting 2:

- {Pelé, Maradona}
- {Pelé, Eusebio}
- {Maradona, Eusebio}

So ${3\choose 2}=3$ combinations

Notice that elements are unique, and it's not important in which order they are taken.

More formally, we talk about the number of subsets of size k (*k-combinations*) from a set of n distinct elements:
$${n\choose k}={n(n-1)...(n-k+1)\over k(k-1)...(1)} = {n!\over (n-k)!k!}$$

Using factorial notation, we can see it as if we started by *counting* the total number of ways to arrange n elements in ordered sequences of size n (a.k.a. permutations), which is n factorial or $n!=n*(n-1)*(n-2)...*1$, but since the sequences of the first $k$ elements (from 1 to $(−)!$) are being counted within $n!$ we must discount them, that is, we divide by ${(n-k)!}$; finally, since k! sequences are just 1 combination, we further *discount* them, dividing again by $k!$.

It's also known as the Binomial Coefficient. You will see it written as:

- ${n\choose k}$, or as
- $C^n_k$
- $C(n,k)$
- ${}_nC_k$
- ${}^nC_k$, or
- $C_{n,k}$

Answer (score 0):

Number of words of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ such that $k$ letters are $a$. When you expand the LHS this characterization immediately implies the RHS.