# A company of 25 people, would like to choose their representative. How many ways are there to choose 3 representatives for the company?

Tags: combinatorics

A company of 25 people would like to choose their representative. How many ways are there to choose 3 representatives for the company ?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! I suggest generalizing the question more and showing how you tried to understand or answer it to help us answer your question better. Consider checking https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/950283 to see how you can improve this question.

Answer (score 2):

It would be ${25 \choose 3}$, have a look at this question: [What is $ {n\choose k}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2338603/976076)

Comment: please avoid answering no effort questions